# How to setup C++ continous build on Hudson / Jenkins

Tags: hudson

I would like to Hudson/Jenkins for our C++ builds for Continuous integration. We are using CMake for make files and subversion for soruce control.

Can you please let me know the steps to setup C++ builds on Hudson (may be using the sample project)

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 7):

1. Create the project in Jenkins
2. Add a Subversion SCM, add the repository url
3. Create the schedule ( try with a `* * * * *` for first try)
4. Add a new step for the build (shell script) that will launch the compilation
5. If you have tests, add a new step (shell script) that will launch the tests
6. List files or directories (artifacts) to archive
7. Save project
8. Launch it

If it fails somewhere, check console output and correct the failing step.